# How do you set ASP.NET Development Web Server to not cache any content?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, caching

I use the ASP.NET Development Web server (also known as the Visual Studio Development Web server) to do local web site debugging and testing.

I've pretty much found exact functionality with IIS with the dev web server.  However - where can you manage the settings of the dev web server - specifically regarding never caching any content - ever?

This of course is useful in a development scenario where I dont want to have to clear my cache...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so much the server you need to worry about doing caching.  It's your browser.  With that in mind, the shift-key is your friend.  Just hold down the shift key while clicking refresh for a page and your browser will clear any cached content for the page.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip - I guess what I was hoping for was the ability to add a Cache-Control header to all content served from the Dev web server.  I would rather not fiddle with browser cache settings as I might hit different servers that I want to use different settings for.

Answer (score 0):

Set your browser settings to download content every time. This is in various places depending on which browser you use. Even with this setting though, Ctrl-F5 forces a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Set cache duration of the Webservice method to 0.

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration=0)]
public string mymethod(string s)
{

}
```

Note: If you only change the content of the method and use Ajax to call it, you'll need to **"Rebuild"** instead of just "Run" the project.